# spring-boot-starter-quartz implements job vs extends QuartzJobBean

Tags: spring-boot, jobs, quartz

I'm using Quartz Scheduler in one of my projects. There are two main ways to create a Quartz job:

1. implement `org.quartz.Job` class
2. extend `org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean` (which implements org.quartz.Job class)

The last part of the QuartzJobBean javadoc is confusing :

```
* Note that the preferred way to apply dependency injection to Job instances is via a JobFactory: 
that is, to specify SpringBeanJobFactory as Quartz JobFactory (typically via
SchedulerFactoryBean.setJobFactory SchedulerFactoryBean's "jobFactory" property}). 
This allows to implement dependency-injected Quartz Jobs without a dependency on Spring base classes.*
```

For a pure Spring (or SpringBoot) use, I suppose that it is better to extend QuartzJobBean. I'm right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, since a `QuartzJobBean` is a `Job`, any API call that will accept a `Job` will accept a `QuartzJobBean`, but not visa versa.  So if you need a `QuartzJobBean` because some API call expects you to pass it one, then there's your answer.

Otherwise, the answer depends on if you want to make use of (and be tied to) the functionality provided by `QuartzJobBean`.  If you look at the source code for that class, you'll see that the sole gain in subclassing `QuartzJobBean` over implementing `Job`, is that `QuartzJobBean` performs this logic before passing control to your code:

```
    try {
        BeanWrapper bw = PropertyAccessorFactory.forBeanPropertyAccess(this);
        MutablePropertyValues pvs = new MutablePropertyValues();
        pvs.addPropertyValues(context.getScheduler().getContext());
        pvs.addPropertyValues(context.getMergedJobDataMap());
        bw.setPropertyValues(pvs, true);
    }
    catch (SchedulerException ex) {
        throw new JobExecutionException(ex);
    }
```

So if you extend the `QuartzJobBean` class and implement the `executeInternal` method, this code runs before your code.  If you implement the `Job` class and the  `execute` method, it does not.  That's the only difference between the two approaches in terms of what actually happens when your job runs.

So to answer your question, ask yourself "do I want to take advantage of the above code?".  If the answer is Yes, then extend `QuartzJobBean` to take advantage of that functionality.  If you don't need this added functionality, don't want it, and/or don't want to be locked into the dependencies implied by the above code, then you should implement `Job` to avoid this code and its dependencies.  My personal approach would be to implement `Job` unless I had some reason to extend `QuartzJobBean` instead.

Comment: So what this try-catch code in QuartzJobBean really does ?

Comment: Per the Spring documentation for the `execute` method of the `QuartzJobBean` class: **"This implementation applies the passed-in job data map as bean property values"**.  I'm not familiar with this code, so I don't feel confident in adding anything to that description.